Non-Storyboard / Programmatically-Generated UIViewControllers
I have been researching how to add some special effects (fireworks) to my app, and doing so appears to require the programmatic generation of UIViews and UIViewControllers, as well as no longer being able to use Storyboard-drawn segues in a few areas. After a lot of research, I have found a tremendous amount of conflicting information, leaving me with several issues, the first of which is noted below:
In my current app I have programmatically generated a scrollable UITextView containing UILabels and UIButtons (associated with @objc functions), all within a Storyboard-drawn UIViewController. My attempts to do the same within a programmatically-generated UIViewController (and delegate) have resulted in a UITextView that will not scroll at all.
I’m using Swift 5, UIKit, and Xcode 15.0.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions you may have as to why my UITextView will not scroll.
I have included the some of the code for a stripped-down hard-coded test version, including “ViewController”, “GameViewController”, “UIViewController+Extensions”, and “NSLayoutConstraint+Extensions”. I have made no changes to AppDelegate and SceneDelegate, so they are not included herein. The view associated with ViewController is drawn in the “Main” storyboard, and it simply includes a label at the top and two buttons, one setting a variable to generate fireworks, and the other to not generate them.
I create a UIScrollView and a UIViewController in ViewController as follows:
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let scrollView :UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        return scrollView
    }()
    
    @IBAction func aYesShowFireworks(_ sender: Any) {
        aCreateView()
        aCreateController()
    }
    
    func aCreateView() {
        view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        scrollView.frame = view.frame
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.pin(view: scrollView, to: view)
    }
    
    func aCreateController() {
        GameViewController().view.frame = view.frame
        GameViewController().view.frame.origin.x = scrollView.contentSize.width
        scrollView.contentSize.width += view.frame.size.width
        add(child: GameViewController(), in: scrollView)
    }
}

I programmatically generate a UITextView in GameViewController as follows:
class GameViewController : UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    let vc: ViewController = ViewController()
    let screenLabel = UILabel()
    let gameStatusTextview = UITextView(frame: .zero)
    var scount = 0
    var xPosition = 7
    var yPosition = 0
    
    func aRefreshView () {
        let subViews = self.gameStatusTextview.subviews
        for subview in subViews {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        screenLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 300, height: 50)
        screenLabel.text = "Fireworks Experiment 03"
        screenLabel.textColor = appColorBlack
        screenLabel.backgroundColor = appColorLightBlue
        screenLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        screenLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
        view.addSubview(screenLabel)
        gameStatusTextview.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 100, width: 380, height: 412)
        gameStatusTextview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        gameStatusTextview.delegate = self
        gameStatusTextview.isEditable = false
        gameStatusTextview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        gameStatusTextview.isScrollEnabled = true
        gameStatusTextview.backgroundColor = appColorMediumGreen
        gameStatusTextview.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic
        view.addSubview(gameStatusTextview)
        while scount < 5 {
            configureLabel(...)
            gameStatusTextview.addSubview(each label)
            configureButton(...)
            gameStatusTextview.addSubview(each button)
            yPosition += 58
            xPosition = 7
            scount += 1
        }
        
        xPosition = 175
        yPosition = 650
        
        configureButtonMain(...)
        view.addSubview(return button)
    }
    
    func configureLabel (labelNameIn: UILabel, textIn: String, textColorIn: UIColor,
                         backgroundColorIn: UIColor, xPositionIn: Int, yPositionIn: Int,
                         widthIn: Int, heightIn: Int, boldOrRegularIn: String, fontSizeIn: CGFloat)          {
        
        labelNameIn.frame = CGRect(x: xPositionIn, y: yPositionIn, width: widthIn,
                                   height: heightIn)
        labelNameIn.text = textIn
        labelNameIn.textColor = textColorIn
        labelNameIn.backgroundColor = backgroundColorIn
        labelNameIn.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        labelNameIn.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSizeIn, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
        return
    }
    
    func configureButton (buttonNameIn: UIButton, xPositionIn: Int, yPositionIn: Int,
                          textIn: String, textColorIn: UIColor, backgroundColorIn: UIColor,
                          selectorIdx: Int) {
        
        var buttonFontSize: CGFloat = 0
        buttonFontSize = 15
        
        buttonNameIn.frame = CGRect(x: xPositionIn, y: yPositionIn, width: 0, height: 0)
        
        buttonNameIn.setTitle(textIn, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        buttonNameIn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
        buttonNameIn.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        buttonNameIn.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        buttonNameIn.setTitleColor(textColorIn, for: .normal)
        buttonNameIn.backgroundColor = backgroundColorIn
        buttonNameIn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: buttonFontSize, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
        buttonNameIn.sizeToFit()
        buttonNameIn.addTarget(self,
                               action: selectorNames[selectorIdx],
                               for: .touchUpInside)
        return
    }
    
    func configureButtonMain (buttonNameIn: UIButton, xPositionIn: Int, yPositionIn: Int,
                              textIn: String, textColorIn: UIColor, backgroundColorIn: UIColor,
                              selectorIdx: Int) {
        
        var buttonFontSize: CGFloat = 0
        buttonFontSize = 15
        
        buttonNameIn.frame = CGRect(x: xPositionIn, y: yPositionIn, width: 0, height: 0)
        buttonNameIn.setTitle(textIn, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        buttonNameIn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
        buttonNameIn.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        buttonNameIn.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        buttonNameIn.setTitleColor(textColorIn, for: .normal)
        buttonNameIn.backgroundColor = backgroundColorIn
        buttonNameIn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: buttonFontSize, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
        buttonNameIn.sizeToFit()
        buttonNameIn.addTarget(self,
                               action: selectorNames[selectorIdx],
                               for: .touchUpInside)
        return
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        aRefreshView()
    }
}

Here is UIViewController+Extensions.swift
import UIKit.UIViewController

extension UIViewController {
    
    remove child controller */
    func add(child childViewController: UIViewController) {
        beginAddChild(child: childViewController)
        view.addSubview(childViewController.view)
        endAddChild(child: childViewController)
    }
    
    add child controller in a specific view */
    func add(child childViewController: UIViewController, in view: UIView) {
        beginAddChild(child: childViewController)
        view.addSubview(childViewController.view)
        endAddChild(child: childViewController)
    }
    
    add child controller in a specific view with a set frame */
    func add(child childViewController: UIViewController, in view: UIView, with frame:CGRect) {
        beginAddChild(child: childViewController)
        childViewController.view.frame = frame
        view.addSubview(childViewController.view)
        endAddChild(child: childViewController)
    }
    
    remove child controller */
    func remove(child childViewController:UIViewController){
        childViewController.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: false)
        childViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        childViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        childViewController.removeFromParent()
        childViewController.endAppearanceTransition()
    }
    
    extract these common methods out to avoid code duplication */
    private func beginAddChild(child childViewController:UIViewController){
        childViewController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
        self.addChild(childViewController)
    }
    
    private func endAddChild(child childViewController:UIViewController){
        childViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        childViewController.endAppearanceTransition()
    }
}

Here is NSLayoutConstraint+Extensions.swift
import UIKit

extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    
    class func pin(view:UIView, to superview:UIView) {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor),
            view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
}


First comment: include enough code so we can copy/paste/run. For example, don't post configureLabel(...) -- include valid parameters. Don't use appColorBlack without defining it. Second comment: why are you adding labels and buttons as subviews to a UITextView?

Thank you very much for taking the time to read my question and provide feedback. You are the only one so far and I truly appreciate it. Your first comment is spot on, but when I posted this question, I wanted to include the whole program, but doing so exceeded the 30,000 character limit by 15,000. This is why I removed so much out of the code. If you can tell me how to provide the entire program I will gladly do so.

Regarding your second comment, please look at Phase 10 Easy Score in the App Store. The second screen shows a UITextView defined as a blank area within the storyboard. In the screen's ViewController, I programmatically add labels for the player names, status, phase, and points, each via addSubview. I do the same for 5 buttons per player, again via addSubview. Up to 15 players are allowed. The problem is that everything is defined in the storyboard. I am trying to add fireworks onto this screen when a player wins, but with no storyboard. This question describes the first of four issues I have.

Are you talking about this screen? https://i.sstatic.net/V0b7vBUt.png ... I don't see anything that would be a UITextView?

Yes. The UITextView starts immediately above the yellow line containing "Donna", and ends immediately below the row of 5 buttons ("Clear Phase" through "View History") that are below "Bob".  The area shows 4 players, but it is scrollable so up to 15 players are supported. The UITextView background color is the same as the rest of the screen, i.e., green on green.

Hmmm.... highly unlikely that is a UITextView with embedded labels and buttons. It looks like a typical UITableView.

Trust me, it’s a UITextView. I wrote the code. All the player names, status information, and buttons are added programmatically via addSubview. But as I mentioned, the UITextView is defined in the storyboard. As soon as I removed the storyboard in my test program and added the UITextView via addSubview, it stopped scrolling. In fact,

The viewDidLoad runs 3 times per screen display, and the buttons don’t work. I got the buttons to work by bringing the UITextView to the front. (Sorry about the break. I accidentally tapped “Add comment”.)

Bob ... I have no idea why you are adding labels and buttons as subviews of a UITextView. Is it just for the scrolling? Or are you using some other features of the text view? I would expect this to be much more straightforward to use a UIScrollView or a UITableView. Here's a quick look at a table view implementation: https://imgur.com/a/ZjeoiIe

Don, when I wrote this app a few years ago I was in the process of teaching myself Swift, and I chose the UITextView purely for its scrolling ability. And now since I’m just updating the code to add fireworks, I’d rather not change the logic to use a different mechanism. Is there any way I can get my entire test program to you so that perhaps you could see what’s going on? My original app is about 16k lines of code, but my test app is only a few hundred or so. I’ve never actually counted it and I’m responding from my phone.

GitHub is a good place to post a project.

Ok. I’ll post it later tonight when I get home. Thanks.

Don, I created a repository in Github at https://github.com/rjalessi/FireWorks-Experiment.git  This is the first time I have ever used Github, so please let me know if you can access it.

Just to clarify ... if you have more than 4 players, the "player rows" should scroll vertically within the Green rectangle (the text view)? Or... should the Green rectangle grow in height, so the entire view scrolls (including the "Fireworks Experiment 03" label and the "Return Home" button?

If there are more than 4 players, the "player rows" should scroll vertically within the UITextView. The "Fireworks Experiment 03" label and "Return Home" button always remain fixed in position.

I have no idea what you might have done with your original Storyboard approach... a UITextView will not scroll simply by adding subviews to it.
You can "fix" your scrolling issue with TWO edits, and ONE new line in GameViewController...
Use a scroll view instead of a text view:
//let gameStatusTextview = UITextView()
let gameStatusTextview = UIScrollView()

Xcode will show you an error, so jump to it and comment-out (or delete) this line:
//gameStatusTextview.isEditable = false

Then, find your print("\(self) \(#function) player loop ended") line of code, and add this above it:
    // gameStatusTextview is now a UIScrollView, so
    //  set the .contentSize to make it scrollable
    //  we use 0 as the width, because we only want vertical scrolling
    gameStatusTextview.contentSize = .init(width: 0, height: yPosition)
    
    print("\(self) \(#function) player loop ended")

Now, you're using a UIScrollView instead of a UITextView, and your "player rows" will scroll vertically.

You also commented that "The viewDidLoad runs 3 times per screen display" ...
In aCreateController() in your ViewController:
func aCreateController() {
    print("\(self) \(#function) about to add child GameViewController in scrollView")
    print("     - GameViewController=\(GameViewController())")
    GameViewController().view.frame = view.frame
    GameViewController().view.frame.origin.x = scrollView.contentSize.width
    scrollView.contentSize.width += view.frame.size.width
    add(child: GameViewController(), in: scrollView)
    print("\(self) \(#function) added child GameViewController in scrollView")
    print("     - GameViewController=\(GameViewController())")
}

Every place you have this: GameViewController() you are creating a new instance of that controller (and then immediately discarding it).
Change that func to:
func aCreateController() {
    print("\(self) \(#function) about to add child GameViewController in scrollView")
    let vc = GameViewController()
    add(child: vc, in: scrollView)
    vc.view.frame = view.frame
    vc.view.frame.origin.x = scrollView.contentSize.width
    scrollView.contentSize.width += view.frame.size.width
    print("\(self) \(#function) added child GameViewController in scrollView")
}


As far as adding "Fireworks" -- that is a completely different topic. If you need help with that, post it as a new question.

Thanks Don! I'm going out for the day, but I quickly made the first change to convert the UITextView to a UIScrollView, and it worked perfectly! I'll try your other change later today or tomorrow, and I'll also convert my original app too.

Your other suggestion also worked to resolve the multiple execution problem. Thanks again! I have a list of a few components I need to work in my test program before I attempt to apply them to my actual app. I’ll post another question if I run into any problems. Thanks again!

Don, I have abbreviated the code in the repository. It now has 3 UIViewControllers. I can go forward from #1 (storyboard) to #2 (add child) to #3 (storyboard), and backward from #3 to #2. But going back from #2 to #1 leaves #2 partially showing underneath. I've tried a few methods, but only the current one (which instantiates #1) works at all (although not correctly). Can you help me with this, after which I'll finally move on the the final fireworks phase? Thanks.

@BobA - way too much for comments here on Stack Overflow. Go to your GitHub repository - Select "Settings" -> "Collaborators" - Add me -- my GitHub ID is the same as here: DonMag ... I can then push changes to your code along with inline comments.

The update is complete.

@BobA - I pushed changes to your GitHub project. Look for comments that begin // DonMag -. The main problem was that your "Return Home" button was presenting a new instance of viewController instead of removing the GameViewController added as a child.

Don, it worked perfectly! Thanks!! Now I'll start working on the final "fireworks" phase.

Using the following SVC = storyboard-defined UIViewController, PVC = programmatically-generated UIViewController, here’s the situation: SVC1->SVC2->PVC3->SVC4
I can go from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, & 3 to 4. I can go from 4 to 3, 3 to 2, & 2 to 1. I don’t know how to go from 3 to 1.
My code is as follows:
1 to 2: storyboard-defined link
2 to 3: PVC3 is added as a child in SVC2, via this code:

scrollView.frame = view.frame
view.addSubview(scrollView)
NSLayoutConstraint.pin(view: scrollView, to: view)
let vc = PVC3()
add(child: vc, in: scrollView)
vc.returnToSVC2 = { [  weak self] in
guard let self = self else { return }
remove(child: vc)
scrollView.removeFromSuperview()
}
3 to 4: This code:
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: “Main”, bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “SVC4Id”)

controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullscreen
controller.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
4 to 3: This code:
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
3 to 2: This code in PVC3:
Public var returnToSVC2: (()->())?
returnToSVC2?()
2 to 1: storyboard-defined link
3 to 1: All I get is a completely black screen.
Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

@BobA - as you can see, posting code in comments is pretty worthless. "All I get is a completely black screen" -- use Debug View Hierarchy to see what's actually there. Based on your earlier code, it's very possible you added a "full screen" black-background view and never removed it.

I've never used the Debug View Hierarchy. I tried it, but it showed an image, which when I rotated it did not label anything. So, I created a GitHub repository at https://github.com/BobAle22/Phase-10-Easy-Score. If you can build and run it, the easiest way to recreate the problem is to choose "Start A New Game", then "Start From Scratch", and finally "Start Over". Not all the buttons on the Game screen work yet, as I am still converting that UIViewController to use code rather than the storyboard. Thanks for all your help.

@BobA -- First, get rid of every self.view.isHidden = true line. I can't think of any situation where that would be a good thing to do. Second, in aStartOverClicked() in TheGame class, change dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) to returnToStartNewGame?().

Your suggestion worked perfectly, thank you. The reason for the "self.view.isHidden = true" lines was to solve a problem when returning to the initial Welcome screen from a distance of several UIViewControllers down the chain. When doing so, I found that all the intermediate UIViewControllers would appear for a fraction of a second until the target destination was reached. My solution was to hide each one when Xcode generated code behind the scenes to traverse the chain backward. If you know of a better solution, I'd be happy to implement it.

Also, the closure solution you provided works well when returning to the previous UIViewController. Is there a different method to be used when traversing from VC1 - VC2 - VC3 - VC4, and VC4 wants to return to VC1 or perhaps VC2? (Assume VC3 programmatically generates VC4, and VC1, 2, & 3 are storyboard-defined.)

@BobA - a closure itself has nothing to do with navigating between controllers... in this case, it's used as a "callback" so code in one controller can communicate with code in another controller -- that is, tell the first controller "I'm done, so get rid of me." I realize that you were just starting when you initially wrote this app, but there are so many things wrong with your structure that it would be impossible (and way out-of-scope) to try and discuss here....

@BobA - however, if you want to "re-do" things, start by learning about UINavigationController ... learn about re-useable views ... learn about arrays of objects (instead of dozens of declared objects) ... etc

Will do. Thanks again for all your help.
